# cmake - Header files of shared library not found

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, header-files

I am making a custom library that I want to be installable for users. However, when I try to use my own library in a cmake executable, I get a build error saying that the library headers were not found.

**The library `CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(mylibrary)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Register a library - This will created lib[xxx].so
add_library(mylibrary SHARED src/library.cpp)

configure_file(mylibrary.pc.in mylibrary.pc @ONLY)

# List the /include directory
target_include_directories(mylibrary PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>  
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

install(TARGETS mylibrary
        EXPORT mylibraryConfig
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

export(TARGETS mylibrary
        FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibraryConfig.cmake")

install(EXPORT mylibraryConfig
        DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/mylibrary/cmake"
        NAMESPACE mylibraryConfig::)

install(
        DIRECTORY include
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylibrary.pc
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig)
```

Which I successfully build and install with:

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/libraries/local  # Use non-standard destination
$ make && make install
```

**The executable`CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(myexecutable)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(mylibrary REQUIRED)

add_executable(myexecutable src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myexecutable PUBLIC mylibrary)

target_include_directories(myexecutable PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

I can prepare cmake for this project:

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/libraries/local # Use non-standard location
```

However, building it fails:

```
$ make
fatal error: mylibrary/library.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <mylibrary/library.h>
```

To my understanding the location of the library (binaries and headers) is embedded in the installed package. And through `find_package()` that information retrieved, so why isn't it working here?

**Similar questions:**

- I largely based my library cmake on: [How to create a shared library with cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511496/how-to-create-a-shared-library-with-cmake)
- Same problem but I am already using `target_include_directories`: [Cmake Linking Shared Library: "No such file or directory" when include a header file from library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060164/cmake-linking-shared-library-no-such-file-or-directory-when-include-a-header)

Comment: As far as I know `find_package()` may not succeed and not even report any message about that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711654...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711654/how-do-i-know-if-find-package-succeeds-in-cmake).

Comment: If I run `cmake ..` (without the `DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`) for the program, I get a neat error like "cannot find package mylibrary". So I'm inclined to think that part works.

Comment: As you namespaced your shared library target in the config file you need to reference it with the full name when using `find_package`, i.e. use `mylibraryConfig::mylibrary` in the `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: Yup, that's it! I just removed the `NAMESPACE` bit. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Or I'll post it myself later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a shared library target is namespaced in the config file you need to reference it with the full name in the downstream packages when using `find_package`, i.e. you need to use

```
target_link_libraries(myexecutable PUBLIC mylibraryConfig::mylibrary)
```

**Alternatively**, remove the namespace from the install by replacing

```
install(EXPORT mylibraryConfig
        DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/mylibrary/cmake"
        NAMESPACE mylibraryConfig::)
```

...with:

```
install(EXPORT mylibraryConfig
        DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/mylibrary/cmake")
```